# How to open create form on click of N:N relationship subgrid + button? currently, it shows lookup search behavior

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, ribbon, subgrid

I have N:N relationship between account and custom address entity and on account form, I have subgrid for custom address. On click of subgrid + button, it shows lookup search. But I need to change that to show create form popup. I know in this scenario, I should have used 1:N relationship between account and custom address but at this point, I cannot change that. I tried hiding "add existing associated" button on ribbon but that was hiding + button itself. I want to subgrid + button but want to open create form on its click event. Any help or pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make the Account lookup field as “Business required” in N:N entity form, then it will work as expected.

Then, If you have a quick create form & “Allow quick create” is enabled for that N:N entity, (+) will open the QC form. If not “Information” Main Form will popup.

When Account lookup is optional, in-line lookup search experience is default.

[Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2014/05/sub-grid-add-action-behavior-in-dynamics-crm/)

Comment: I can't see how this would work...? The only way to edit attributes on an N:N entity is if it is a "custom" N:N entity (i.e. manually creating a link entity that is simple lookups to two other entities). The link you posted would work fine for 1:N relationships but OP referred to (presumably native) N:N

Comment: @GregOwens Lookup search experience is the only available option for Native N:N subgrid. We cannot achieve entity form experience in Native N:N relationship. Manual N:N is simply 1:N relationships between a new intersect entity and other 2 entities & this can be achieved: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2013/04/29/availability-of-add-new-and-add-existing-buttons-in-sub-grids

Comment: I think this is exactly my point Arun - I don't see how the solution you originally posted is actually possible ("Make the Account lookup field 'business required' in N:N entity form")  This isn't possible - or did I miss something?

Comment: @GregOwens where do you see this is is about native N:N ? Am I missing anything?

Comment: I guess we are approaching this on different assumptions. Whenever I read "N:N relationships" in the context of Dynamics 365 / CRM, I *always* assume it is a "native" relationship (versus manual intersect entity). The OP didn't say that they had created a manual intersect entity so I naturally assume they have a native N:N relationship. In that case, your solution cannot work :)

Comment: @GregOwens exactly. Native N:N don’t have create form, OP wanted the create form popup, so it’s not native. :)

Comment: Ahh *that's* where we've differed then;I'd interpreted that the OP wanted to show the create form of the "custom address entity". Your solution makes sense to me now.